# How to take specific users from JSON file?

Tags: json, python-2.7, robotframework

I have a JSON file from where i am taking users data and performing operations.how to get the specific users from JSON file?

Here is the JSON file:

```
    "users" : {
            "ABC": {
                "ip": "10.50.10.XXXX:5555",
                "username": "user1@gmail.com",
                "password": "xyz123",
                "displayname": "user 1",
                "Mode": "Personal",
                "phonenumber": "14084xxxx",
                "pstndisplay": "+1 408-xxx-xxx"
            }
            "EFG": {
                "ip": "10.50.10.XXXX:5555",
                "username": "user2@gmail.com",
                "password": "xyz123",
                "displayname": "user 2",
                "Mode": "Personal",
                "phonenumber": "14084xxxx",
                "pstndisplay": "+1 408-xxx-xxx"
            }

             "XYZ": {
                "ip": "10.50.10.XXXX:5555",
                "username": "user3@gmail.com",
                "password": "xyz123",
                "displayname": "user 3",
                "Mode": "Personal",
                "phonenumber": "14084xxxx",
                "pstndisplay": "+1 408-xxx-xxx"
            }
```

here how i am parsing the JSON data:

```
  ${the file as string}=    Get File    ${users_json_path}
      ${parsed}=    Evaluate  json.loads("""${the file as string}""", object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)     json, collections
      ${properties}=  Set Variable  ${parsed["users"]}
      Log  ${properties}
      :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{properties}
      \  ${sub dict}=    Get From Dictionary    ${properties}    ${key}
      \  Log  ${sub dict}
      \  Signin  ${sub dict}[ip]   ${sub dict}[username]   ${sub dict}[password]  ${sub dict}[Mode]
      \  Log  ${key} is successfully signed in.
```

here is the test case:

```
Given Number of users signs in to their respective devices  ${ABC} 
      Then ABC sees that Sign in is successful
      And No action is taken for 30 seconds
      When ABC signs out from the device
      Then ABC sees that sign out was successful
```

i am expecting when i wanted to perform sign in by using particular user like ABC, it will perform sign in operation with ABC only, but it's performing sign in operation using all the users by taking the data from users.how to perform sign in operation by taking particular user from JSON?

Comment: can you share what you tried so far and what is blocking you?

Comment: i am trying to perform sign in operation by using JSON data on particular user, but it's taking all users and performing sign in, but i want to perform sign in by using particular user. how to make it will take only particular user in above test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add into start of loop:

```
Continue For Loop If    $key != 'ABC'
```

This will skip "Signin" if user is not ABC.